# update query in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wonder can I use the update query in sparksql just like:

```
sqlContext.sql("update users set name = '*' where name is null")
```

I got the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Unsupported language features in query:update users set name = '*' where name is null
```

If the sparksql does not support the update query or am i writing the code incorrectly?

Comment: May be possible version issue

Comment: I use spark-1.6.1.

Comment: Now it's possible, with [Databricks Delta Lake](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-intro.html)

Comment: Spark SQL now supports update, delete and such data modification operations if the underlying table is in delta format. Check this out:
[https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#update-a-table](https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#update-a-table)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Spark SQL doesn't support `UPDATE` statements yet.

Hive has started supporting `UPDATE` since hive version 0.14. But even with Hive, it supports updates/deletes only on those tables that support **transactions**, it is mentioned in the [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update).

See the answers in databricks forums confirming that [UPDATES/DELETES are not supported in Spark SQL](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6007/can-we-use-updatedelete-queries-in-databricks-with.html) as it [doesn't support transactions](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/3093/does-spark-sql-support-hive-transactions-yet.html). If we think, supporting random updates is very complex with most of the storage formats in big data. It requires scanning huge files, updating specific records and rewriting potentially TBs of data. It is not normal SQL.

Comment: There is an open ticket in the Spark project to improve support for Hive transaction tables (i.e. Hive tables which support updates) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348

Comment: Any new updates on this whether it is supported now ? or any alternative to do the same ?