# how to change column value in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Sql, I can easily update some column value using UPDATE, for example:
I have a table (student) like:

```
student_id, grade, new_student_id
123             B      234
555             A      null

UPDATE Student
SET student_id = new_student_id
WHERE new_student_id isNotNull
```

How can I do it in Spark using SparkSql(PySpark)?

Comment: Realted to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517371/update-query-in-spark-sql

Answer (score 6):

You can use `withColumn` to overwrite the existing `new_student_id` column with the original `new_student_id` value if is not null, or otherwise  the value from the `student_id` column is used:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when

#Create sample data
students = sc.parallelize([(123,'B',234),(555,'A',None)]).toDF(['student_id','grade','new_student_id'])

#Use withColumn to use student_id when new_student_id is not populated
cleaned = students.withColumn("new_student_id", 
          when(col("new_student_id").isNull(), col("student_id")).
          otherwise(col("new_student_id")))
cleaned.show()
```

Using your sample data as input:

```
+----------+-----+--------------+
|student_id|grade|new_student_id|
+----------+-----+--------------+
|       123|    B|           234|
|       555|    A|          null|
+----------+-----+--------------+
```

the  output data looks as follows:

```
+----------+-----+--------------+
|student_id|grade|new_student_id|
+----------+-----+--------------+
|       123|    B|           234|
|       555|    A|           555|
+----------+-----+--------------+
```