# Spark SQL - regexp_replace not updating the column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

I ran the following query in Hive and it successfully updated the column value in the table: `select id, regexp_replace(full_name,'A','C') from table`

But when I ran the same query from Spark SQL, it did not update the actual records

```
hiveContext.sql("select id, regexp_replace(full_name,'A','C') from table")
```

but when I do a `hiveContext.sql("select id, regexp_replace(full_name,'A','C') from table").show()` -- it displays A replaced with C successfully ... only in the display and not in the actual table

I tried to assign the result to another variable

```
val vFullName = hiveContext.sql("select id, regexp_replace(full_name,'A','C') from table")
```

and then

```
vFullName.show() -- it displays the original values without replacement
```

How do I get the value replaced in the table from SparkSQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517371/update-query-in-spark-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: you can also create a new table with the updated column using CTAS.