# How to execute simple SQL query such as update in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, hadoop2

I want to execute **update** query in SQL using `pyspark` based some logic I am using. All I could find is *documentation* on how to read from `SQL`

BUT

> there are no proper examples of executing update or create statement.

Comment: df2 = spark.sql("SELECT field1 AS f1, field2 as f2 from table1") http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: I want to run update query not Select. I am doing comparisons between two data frames if I found a difference I need to update the value in SQL table

Comment: SQL doesnt support update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517371/update-query-in-spark-sql

Comment: As @MiguelSantos pointed out, SQL doesn't support updates, so you need to refactor your query to a transformation. For example you could add a new column based on your logic, or you could overwrite an existing column.

Comment: thank you @MiguelSantos and Jaco. Guess I'll have to use sqlalchemy to update it.