# How to do T-SQL operations UPDATE ... SET ... in pyspark?

Tags: python, t-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have T-SQL queries which are needed to be coded in pyspark. However, Pyspark doesn't support all SQL operations, and thereby you have to build your own logic accordingly. I've managed to convert many of the queries but I couldn't be sure how to do this in Pyspark.

Here is the T-SQL query:

```
UPDATE #TERT A SET TARIH=B.DTARIH
FROM KMLK B
WHERE A.NO=B.NO
AND A.TARIH=''
AND B.DURUM=1
```

Can you help me to produce UPDATE ... SET logic in pyspark ?

Comment: I was going to suggest this qusetion as a duplicate, [update query in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517371/update-query-in-spark-sql), but the 2 answers that say it's possible as link only and so not useful. They do, however, link to the relevant [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#update-a-table)

Comment: @ThomA But what if our tables are not in Delta format :) which are not actually. What is the role of SET here ? maybe we can achieve update by overwriting the dataframe after filtering

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with PySpark. I just goggled the problem and found that instantly; your question doesn't demonstrate you've researched this problem at all. If you can't implement that solution you should edit your question to explain why and what you're scenario is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution. As may most of you know, there could be several ways to write same logic in SQL. In that sense, we can find a way to do UPDATE-SET operation in different way in Pyspark. "SET" means changing a column value with another according the filters (or Where condition), and UPDATE means updating the relevant table accordingly. So;

```
## Assuming we have loaded the #TERT table into dataframe, which is tert_df in that case. Then,

tert_df = tert_df.alias("A").join(kmlk_df.alias("B"),(col("A.no") == col("B.no")))\
                            .filter((col("A.durum") != "") & (col("B.durum") == 1))\
                            .withColumn("A.tarih", col("B.dtarih")).select("A.*")
```

`withColumn()` does the work i guess. Here is the relevant [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html).
Hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

i will suggest you that you should give a referance where you want to Changing Like

update *tablename set name="Danish" where Address="............."
here we are giving referance that change name at this where adress is this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).